# Is there a way within a Google Apps Script to set a row height to fit the data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

In Google Sheets, after selecting a series of rows and right clicking on one of them, there is an option under Row Height that is Fit to Data.  I would like to do this in a script.

All of my searching says no but I am hopeful.  Columns are covered nicely but rows do not appear to be covered.

Thank you.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60091644/in-a-google-document-how-to-set-a-tables-multiple-rows-height-to-match-the-cell/60096817#60096817)

Answer (score 13):

From what I know it isnt possible to have the rows automatically fit to data, this can only be done for columns with [autoResizeColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#autoResizeColumn(Integer)).

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

sheet.getRange('a1').setValue('Whenever it is a damp, drizzly November in my soul...');

// Sets the first column to a width which fits the text
sheet.autoResizeColumn(1);
```

However, if you know how much space your data will take you can just use a [setRowHeight()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#setRowHeight(Integer,Integer)). I think this is the only option you have for rows, columns seemed to be the prefered part to auto-fit.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// Sets the first row to a height of 200 pixels
sheet.setRowHeight(1, 200);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

This is kind of an old question but it seems that this functionality has since been added.

Now you can use the `autoResizeRows()` function.

The documentation explains it well.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#autoResizeRows(Integer,Integer)

Comment: An error occurs when a value greater than 26 is given. "Exception: Those columns are out of bounds." How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

sheet.setColumnWidths(1, sheet.getMaxColumns(), 120).setRowHeights(1, sheet.getMaxRows(), 21)
```

120 and 21 are current defaults, I'm not sure these values are available via API