# In a Google Document how to set a tables multiple rows' height to match the cell content size?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I can click and drag each horizontal line one by one manually to match amount of content of the cell above it (how many lines of text it has), but what if you have 100 rows?
How can you get from top to the bottom table here without manually dragging each horizontal line?

So, if there is ONE line of text in the whole row height wise, I want the table be ONE line height, not 10 like in the below case in abc row.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by to match the content of the cell above? Are you looking to resize rows automatically to have the content displayed in full?

Comment: @Aerials  the height of the rows is unnecessarily huge. You can see on the bottom table, that it's 1 line height, not many compared to above.

Comment: Why is the height of the rows originally huge? Do you need to do this every time you open the Document?

Comment: I just pasted it from Excel, in Excel sizes are perfect. I mean, it had a lot of text, but column WIDTH was off, and after adjusting width, the height stayed the same. Just deleted the text (confidential) and put in these letters as dummies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

This can be achieved using a bound-to-your-Doc [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound). You can write a function to make all rows' height the minimum possible for tables in the Document, and for those rows with content height larger than minimum, the minimum for that row will be applied (Not hiding any of the content).

#### Example of a function to achieve this:

```js
function fixCellSize() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().alert("All row heights will be minimized to content height.");
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var tables = body.getTables();
  for each (var table in tables) { 
    for (var i=0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++){
      Logger.log("Fantasctic!");
      table.getRow(i).setMinimumHeight(1);
    }
  }
}
```

If you would like to make the function available in the menu, then you could create a [`Custom Menu`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#custom_menus_in_google_docs_sheets_slides_or_forms) with a function like the following:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("Custom Menu").addItem("Fix cell sizes", "fixCellSize").addToUi();
};
```

By putting this functions in a bound script you will get what you are looking for.

You can try it out in this [Document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1r6rB1DzDY7j7UbDFRJYbEcaIJR8dc4zHEMQrJZLp54s/edit?usp=sharing) showcasing it.

#### Recommended reading:

1. [Extending Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs)
2. [Apps Script DocumentApp class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app)

Comment: wow thanks a lot, had no idea you could write code for this :O

Comment: You are welcome! Yes!, the Google APIs are really powerful. Enjoy!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, I get a syntax error when I attempt to save it:

`Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier line: 6 file: Code.gs`