# In a Google Document how to set all rows of all tables height to match the cell content size?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have found this question answered here:
[In a Google Document how to set a tables multiple rows' height to match the cell content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60091644/in-a-google-document-how-to-set-a-tables-multiple-rows-height-to-match-the-cell/64157131?noredirect=1#comment113452961_64157131)
The code looks exactly what I need:

```
 function fixCellSize() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().alert("All row heights will be minimized to content height.");
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var tables = body.getTables();
  for each (var table in tables) { 
    for (var i=0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++){
      Logger.log("Fantasctic!");
      table.getRow(i).setMinimumHeight(1);
    }
  }
}
```

But it does not work anymore.
If added to my script in the document, it shows error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier ..." when saving and mentions the line from the script:

```
for each (var table in tables) {
```

When tried in the sample document provided [in the answer of that question](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1r6rB1DzDY7j7UbDFRJYbEcaIJR8dc4zHEMQrJZLp54s/edit?usp=sharing) it shows error "TypeError: table.getNumRows is not a function"

I have tried various alterations of describing table, tables, diferrent pproaches of getting the rows with no luck.

Any ideas that went wrong in these few months and how to fix the code?

Comment: What's the exact error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I think that your issue is due to V8 runtime. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration#avoid_for_eachvariable_in_object) For example, when you disable V8 runtime and rhino runtime is used, I think that the error of `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier ...` will be removed and the script will work. But in the current stage, I would like to propose to use v8 runtime.
- And when I saw your shared Document, I also found the following script.

  ```
    for (var table in tables) { 
      for (var i=0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++){
        Logger.log("Fantasctic!");
        table.getRow(i).setMinimumHeight(1);
      }
    }
  ```

  - I think that in this case, `table` is the number of the string type. By this, I think that the error of `TypeError: table.getNumRows is not a function` occurs.

When the above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
for each (var table in tables) { 
  for (var i=0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++){
    Logger.log("Fantasctic!");
    table.getRow(i).setMinimumHeight(1);
  }
}
```

And

```
for (var table in tables) { 
  for (var i=0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++){
    Logger.log("Fantasctic!");
    table.getRow(i).setMinimumHeight(1);
  }
}
```

#### To:

```
tables.forEach(table => {
  for (var i=0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++){
    Logger.log("Fantasctic!");
    table.getRow(i).setMinimumHeight(1);
  }
});
```

or

```
tables.forEach(function(table) {
  for (var i=0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++){
    Logger.log("Fantasctic!");
    table.getRow(i).setMinimumHeight(1);
  }
});
```

#### Note:

- In this case, please confirm whether V8 runtime is enabled at the script editor. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime)

#### References:

- [Migrating scripts to the V8 runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)